# Узнать тип атрибута.

Tags: android

Мне нужно узнать тип кастомного атрибута.

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="test" format="string" />
    <attr name="custom_color" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="custom_color2" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Для API 21 и выше есть метод `typedArray.getType(index)`. А как можно узнать тип для версий ниже 21?

Comment: Видимо только страшным перебором вариантов. Но ведь если вы указали тип атрибута в xml, то он никак не может поменяться?

Comment: Не может. Но мне нужно тип программно получить. Я могу color получить как getColor и как getInt. мне нужно точно знать что это цвет или число

Comment: Ну так если у вас `<attr name="custom_color2" format="color" />`, то вы можете задать цвет ссылкой или rgb, но откуда там взяться числу? Т.е. c getColor проблем быть не должно. Посмотрите как работает с атрибутами TextView, там тип нигде не проверяется, но оно работает.

Comment: Это был пример. И там берется число. Мне нужно то что я именно спросил. Мне нужно узнать когда тип. Остальное не проблема. Проблема в определение типа

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/78ccfd5f7e4880597fd90c61453a3be0e7aee5f0/sdk/sources/android-21/android/content/res/TypedArray.java посмотри как сделано здесь и реализуй сам.